# Change values based on strings stored in multiple columns, but individually

Tags: python, pandas, string, apply

Suppose I have a data frame with four columns: A, B, C, D. These contain string data and may also be empty. I need to change each of these values to a category: Yes, No, or Unknown, based on the presence of certain sub-strings within each string. Each comparison is made only based on the value of each respective cell (it does not matter what other columns say).

I have a function, `str2cat`, which handles the logic and assumes the argument it receives (`s`) is a string or `None`. For the sake of a MWE:

```
def str2cat(s):
  if not s or s is None or s.strip() == '': 
    return "Some Category"

  if "some string" in s.str.lower():
    return "Another Category"

  return "Default Category"
```

I currently apply the values I want in each column like this:

```
df["A"] = df["A"].astype(str)
df["B"] = df["B"].astype(str)
df["C"] = df["C"].astype(str)
df["D"] = df["D"].astype(str)
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(str2cat)
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(str2cat)
df["C"] = df["C"].apply(str2cat)
df["D"] = df["D"].apply(str2cat)
```

That's all fine and works fine. But it assumes only 4 columns. Let's assume I have other columns I don't want to apply this function to, and I want to target MANY columns with this function. My thinking was that I can list the targeted columns then only `apply` my function to those:

```
targeted_cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
df[targeted_cols] = df[targeted_cols].astype(str)
df[targeted_cols] = df[targeted_cols].apply(str2cat)
```

But this doesn't work. I get errors about how `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`. I tried adding `axis=1` in my `apply` function to no avail. I tried having my function handle multiple args and had similar errors. I thought maybe a lambda function could unpack the series and feed one value at a time to the function but had no luck.

There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried df[targeted_columns].apply(lambda x: str2cat(*x), axis=1) ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBEDOYA the problem is when I modify my func to accept multiple args, it breaks all the comparisons shown even when I iterate over them. It isn't clear to me how to change my function to work in this instance since it generally checks one value and returns a category (as a string) for each. It also breaks on the initial comparisons I do because of the truth value ambiguity issue I am unsure how to resolve.

Comment: You need to use `applymap`, not `apply`: `df[targeted_cols] = df[targeted_cols].astype(str).applymap(str2cat)`, although vectorial code would be better if possible

Comment: @mozway that worked! I will accept if posted as an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure if this will work without looking at your data, but if you're just looking to apply your function to all columns the below loop should do what you need:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str).apply(str2cat)
```